# Defining eloquent relationship - getting most recent archive

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a group of models that are archived, into a separate archive table for each model. I have defined a relationship from the model to it's archives as follows...

```
public function archives()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ArchivedModel::class, 'original_id', 'id')
        ->orderBy('date_from', 'desc');
}
```

The above works. I get the expected results with...

```
$model = Model::with('archives')->findOrFail(1)->first();
```

I would also like to define a relationship to the most recent archive - which will always exist, I have tried the following but no luck...

```
public function mostRecentArchive()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ArchivedModel::class, 'original_id', 'id')
        ->orderBy('date_from', 'desc')
        ->first();
}
```

... I get

> BadMethodCallException thrown with message "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addEagerConstraints()"

So my question -

**How can I define a relationship to the most recent archive?**

Any pointers would be appretiated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function mostRecentArchive()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ArchivedModel::class, 'original_id', 'id')
        ->orderBy('date_from', 'desc');

}
```

No need to write ->first(); in relationship

Comment: Thanks, kind of obvious now you mention it - will accept your answer when SO lets me...

Comment: if is currect then mark as currect so all are use this ans

Comment: There you go - SO wouldn't let me accept it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

remote first()

```
public function mostRecentArchive()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ArchivedModel::class, 'original_id', 'id')
        ->orderBy('date_from', 'desc')
}
```

Comment: A few seconds too slow! Thanks for the answer though!